# Post to Sinatra API with hyperresource

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

I built an app in Sinatra with Roar (hal/JSON) and now I'm trying to post a new item from my client to this API.

In my Sinatra app I have routes like these:

```
get '/todos/new' do
  @pagetitle = 'New Todo'
  @todo = Todo.new
  @todo.extend(TodoRepresenter)
  @todo.to_json  
  erb :'todos/new'
end

post "/todos" do
  @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])
  if @todo.save
    redirect "todos/#{@todo.id}"
  else
    erb :"todos/new"
  end
end
```

And my client.rb looks like this:

```
require 'hyperresource'
class ApiRequest < HyperResource

api = ApiRequest.new(root: 'http://127.0.0.1:9393',
                    headers: {'Accept' => 'application/vnd.http://127.0.0.1:9393.v1+json'})

api.post '/todos/new', { :title => "a"}
```

This doesn't work. The only way of get a working client is the `get` function:

```
require 'hyperresource'
class ApiRequest < HyperResource

api = ApiRequest.new(root: 'http://127.0.0.1:9393/todos/13',
                    headers: {'Accept' => 'application/vnd.http://127.0.0.1:9393.v1+json'})

todo = api.get
output = todo.body
puts output
```

I don't know how to solve this, and the Github page doesn't tell me either.

---

I changed the API slightly:

```
get '/todos' do
 @pagetitle = 'New Todo'
 @todo = Todo.new
 erb :'todos/new'
end

post "/todos/new" do
 @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])
 @todo.extend(TodoRepresenter)
 @todo.to_json    
 if @todo.save
   redirect "todos/#{@todo.id}"
 else
   erb :"todos/new"
 end
end
```

and also the way of posting in my client:

```
todo = api.get.new_todo.post(title: "Test")
```

In my API console I now get:

```
D, [2014-11-04T17:11:41.875218 #11111] DEBUG -- :   Todo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "todos".* FROM "todos"  WHERE "todos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=new:
```

and a lot of other code.

In my client console I get a lot of code, with a hyper resource server error and a lot of other code.

Comment: You are posting to `'/todos/new'` (with `api.post '/todos/new', { :title => "a"}`,) while you set the post handler on `'/todos'` with `post "/todos" do...`. Bringing them into correspondence should solve an issue.

Comment: @mudasobwa I switcht the names and also my way of posting: todo = api.get.new_todo.post(title: "Test"). At my api server i now get the error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Todo with 'id'=new:

Comment: Wait. Post handler is ready @`/todos` endpoint already. Please simply change it to handle `post "/todos/new" do` and leave everything else intouch. This should help.

Comment: @mudasobwa To bad this doesn't work, see my edit in question, there's what I do have now